# bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found

Tags: python, bash, centos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

After following the instructions on [Doug Hellman's `virtualenvwrapper` post](https://doughellmann.com/posts/virtualenvwrapper/), I still could not fire up a test environment.

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ mkvirtualenv test
-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

It should be noted that I'm using `WORKON_HOME` that is not in my `$HOME`.  I tried looking for `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` as shown in the [`virtualenvwrapper` installation docs](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html), but it does not exist.

I'm running CentOS 6 and python 2.6.6, if this matters.

---

```
# File: ~/.bash_profile
# ...

export WORKON_HOME="/opt/virtual_env/"
source "/opt/virtual_env/bin/virtualenvwrapper_bashrc"
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

For some reason, `virtualenvwrapper.sh` installed in `/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, instead of under `/usr/local/bin`.

The following in my `.bash_profile` works...

```
source "/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
export WORKON_HOME="/opt/virtual_env/"
```

My install seems to work fine without sourcing `virtualenvwrapper_bashrc`

**Solution 2**:

Alternatively as mentioned below, you could leverage the chance that `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is already in your shell's `PATH` and just issue a `` source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` ``

Comment: Setting `WORKON_HOME` to "~/.virtualenvs" ([default value](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html)) allows to set private virtualenvs

Comment: If you install using your distro's package manager, files will be in `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`.  Generally, you should not assume one or the other to be found; that's one of the reasons we have a `PATH` variable.

Comment: This answer was based on installing virtualenvwrapper with pip, which is what I prefer doing.

Comment: It needs to be installed first, `pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: `WORKON_HOME` is optional and has nothing to do with the solution.

Comment: After installing virtualwrapper it says no such file or directory found after the first line of your code

Comment: I found `virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in `/usr/share` Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 70):

Try:

```
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
```

The backticks are command substitution - they take whatever the program prints out and put it in the expression. In this case "which" checks the $PATH to find virtualenvwrapper.sh and outputs the path to it. The script is then read by the shell via 'source'.

If you want this to happen every time you restart your shell, it's probably better to grab the output from the "which" command first, and then put the "source" line in your shell, something like this:

`echo "source /path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.profile`

^ This may differ slightly based on your shell. Also, be careful not to use the a single > as this will truncate your ~/.profile :-o

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to explain how this will solve the problem.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: This solved my problem. But will someone explain why and how?

Comment: The backticks are command substitution - they take whatever the program prints out and put it in the expression. In this case "which" checks the $PATH to find virtualenvwrapper.sh and outputs the path to it. The script is then read by the shell via 'source'.

Answer (score 44):

I had the same issue on OS X 10.9.1 with python 2.7.5.  No issues with `WORKON_HOME` for me, but I did have to manually add `source "/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"` to `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc` in unix) after I ran `pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: Where did you manually add    source "/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"?

Comment: @Gregology I added that line to `~/.bash_profile`. Note that when you first add it you'll either have to reload the terminal (which runs `.bash_profile`) or just run that `source` command directly from the command line.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you had a title with the filename and displayed all the contents so you don't have to get followup questions about "where did you put it?"

Comment: Whether you use `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` is not really directly a consequence of which platform you are usng, though one or the other may be missing on some platforms.  See the Bash manual page for their differences.  Generally, you should only really need this in your `.bash_profile`, but some distros use setups which complicate matters.

Answer (score 28):

**Prerequisites to execute this command -**

1. pip (recursive acronym of **P**ip **I**nstalls **P**ackages)  is a package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python. Many packages can be found in the Python Package Index (PyPI).

   sudo apt-get install python-pip
2. Install Virtual Environment. Used to create virtual environment, to install packages and dependencies of multiple projects isolated from each other.

   sudo pip install virtualenv
3. Install virtual environment wrapper [About virtual env wrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#introduction)

   sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper

**After Installing prerequisites** you need to bring virtual environment wrapper into action to create virtual environment. Following are the steps -

1. set virtual environment directory in path variable-
   `export WORKON_HOME=(directory you need to save envs)`
2. `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh -p $WORKON_HOME`

As mentioned by @Mike, source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` or `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` can used to locate virtualenvwrapper.sh file.

It's best to put above two lines in ~/.bashrc to avoid executing the above commands every time you open new shell. That's all you need to create environment using **mkvirtualenv**

**Points to keep in mind -**

- Under Ubuntu, you may need install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper as root. Simply prefix the command above with sudo.
- Depending on the process used to install virtualenv, the path to virtualenvwrapper.sh may vary. Find the appropriate path by running $ find /usr -name virtualenvwrapper.sh. Adjust the line in your .bash_profile or .bashrc script accordingly.

Comment: Adding a note. On ubuntu 18.04, I had to reboot after install and then it worked.

Comment: @screenmutt Thanks for valuable input. I might have missed it as I use ubuntu 16.04. However, I would like to know after which step did you have to reboot ? Is is after installing pip packages or after setting up "virtual environment directory" ?

Comment: After the install of the wrapper. It worked after that.

Comment: @DanGrahn you don't need to reboot, just need to rerun `.bashrc` - either explicitly `source ~/.bashrc` in your current terminal, or open a new terminal window

Answer (score 18):

**Use this procedure to create virtual env in ubuntu**

**Step 1**

Install pip

```
   sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

**step 2**

Install virtualenv

```
   sudo pip install virtualenv
```

**step 3**

Create a dir to store your virtualenvs (I use ~/.virtualenvs)

```
   mkdir ~/.virtualenvs
```

or use this command to install specific version of python in env

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv
```

**step 4**

```
   sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

**step 5**

```
   sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

**step 6**

Add this two line code at the end of the bashrc file

```
  export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
  source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

**step 7**

Open new terminal (recommended)

**step 8**

Create a new virtualenv

```
  mkvirtualenv myawesomeproject
```

**step 9**

To load or switch between virtualenvs, use the workon command:

```
  workon myawesomeproject
```

**step 10**

To exit your new virtualenv, use

```
 deactivate
```

*and make sure using pip vs pip3*

**OR follow the steps below to install virtual environment using python3**

Install env

```
python3 -m venv my-project-env
```

and activate your virtual environment using the following command:

```
source my-project-env/bin/activate
```

or if you want particular python version

```
virtualenv --python=python3.7.5 myenv
```

Answer (score 7):

**Since I just went though a drag, I'll try to write the answer I'd have wished for two hours ago. This is for people who don't just want the copy&paste solution**

**First:** Do you wonder why copying and pasting paths works for some people while it doesn't work for others?** The main reason, solutions differ are different python versions, 2.x or 3.x. There are actually distinct versions of virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper that work with either python 2 or 3. If you are on python 2 install like so:

```
sudo pip install virutalenv
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

If you are planning to use python 3 install the related python 3 versions

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

**You've successfully installed the packages for your python version and are all set, right?** Well, try it. Type `workon` into your terminal. Your terminal will not be able to find the command (`workon` is a command of virtualenvwrapper). Of course it won't. `Workon` is an executable that will only be available to you once you load/source the file `virtualenvwrapper.sh`. But the official [installation guide](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#) has you covered on this one, right?. Just open your .bash_profile and insert the following, it says in the documentation:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Especially the command `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` seems helpful since the command seems to load/source the desired file `virtualenvwrapper.sh` that contains all the commands you want to work with like `workon` and `mkvirtualenv`. **But yeah, no.** When following the official installation guide, you are very likely to receive the error from the initial post: `mkvirtualenv: command not found`. Still no command is being found and you are still frustrated. So whats the problem here? The problem is that virtualenvwrapper.sh is not were you are looking for it right now. Short reminder ... you are looking here:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

But there is a pretty straight forward way to finding the desired file. Just type

```
which virtualenvwrapper
```

to your terminal. This will search your [PATH](https://medium.com/@jalendport/what-exactly-is-your-shell-path-2f076f02deb4) for the file, since it is very likely to be in some folder that is included in the PATH of your system.

*If your system is very exotic, the desired file will hide outside of a PATH folder. In that case you can find the path to `virtalenvwrapper.sh` with the shell command `find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh`*

Your result may look something like this: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`
Congratulations. `You have found your missing file!`. Now all you have to do is changing one command in your .bash_profile. Just change:

```
source "/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
```

to:

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
```

Congratulations. Virtualenvwrapper does now work on your system. **But you can do one more thing to enhance your solution.** If you've found the file `virtualenvwrapper.sh` with the command `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` you know that it is inside of a folder of the PATH. So if you just write the filename, your file system will assume the file is inside of a PATH folder. So you you don't have to write out the full path. Just type:

```
source "virtualenvwrapper.sh"
```

Thats it. You are no longer frustrated. You have solved your problem. Hopefully.

Comment: I actually just copied and pased your solution

Answer (score 3):

open your bashrc file using

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

go to the bottom of the bashrc file
and copy these lines and paste it

which python3(gives you the python path)

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3


export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
```

which virtualenv (gives you the location of virtualenv)

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

which virtualenvwrapper.sh(returns the location of virtualenvwrapper.sh)

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

please copy these lines in the same order as given above

for more information you can refer to:https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/virtualenv-with-virtualenvwrapper-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Alternatively you can use:

create virtual environment :

```
python3 -m venv <virtual environment name>

virtualenv <virtual environment name>
```

To activate the virtual environment

```
source <virtual environment name>/bin/activate
```

To deactivate the virtual environment

```
deactivate
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Git Bash on Windows 10 and Python36 for Windows I found the virtualenvwrapper.sh in a slightly different place and running this resolved the issue

```
source virtualenvwrapper.sh 
/c/users/[myUserName]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python36/Scripts
```

Comment: Using Windows 10, Git Bash and Python 3.8, for me it was on:
`/c/Users/[myUserName]/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python38/Scripts`

Comment: @Manur thanks, it worked. On running `source virtualenwrapper.sh` , i wasn't able to see this path, when i did `source  /c/Users/[myUserName]/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python38/Scripts`, `mkvirtualenv <name>` worked.

Answer (score 2):

In order to successfully install the `virtualenvwrapper` on Ubuntu 18.04.3 you need to do the following:

1. Install `virtualenv`

   ```
   sudo apt install virtualenv
   ```
2. Install  `virtualenvwrapper`

   ```
   sudo pip install virtualenv
   sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
   ```
3. Add the following to the end of the `.bashrc` file

   ```
   export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs
   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
   source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
   ```
4. Execute the `.bashrc` file

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Create your virtualenv

   ```
   mkvirtualenv your_virtualenv
   ```

Comment: works on ubuntu 20.04 as well. a small correction tho: `WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs` is the default. no need to set that. `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python` is also the default, but when using python3 this is useful. also one should use `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` for the python binary paths

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 and Git Bash this helps me:

1. Create a **~/.bashrc** file (under your user home folder)
2. Add line **export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs** (you must create this folder if it doesn't exist)
3. Add line **source "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\virtualenvwrapper.sh"** (change path for
   your virtualenvwrapper.sh)

**Restart** your git bash and mkvirtualenv command now will work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian

```
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know for what reason, but for me the **virtualenvwrapper.sh** file is located in `/home/aditya/.local/bin` and not in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Just added `source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in my `~/.bashrc` file and it worked well.

(Hope you know you should use `bash` command everytime you update your `.bashrc` .)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue in Ubuntu 14.04 OS with python 2.7.6, by adding below two lines into ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.bashrc in unix) files.

**source "/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"**

**export WORKON_HOME="/opt/virtual_env/"**

And then executing both these lines onto the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, to create the virtual environment, I replace "**pip mkvirtualenv** myproject" by "**mkvirtualenv** myproject" and that works well.