# mkvirtualenv: command not found

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm new to Python virtual environments, so after reading [this tutorial](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial-part-2/) I tried to create my first environment using `virtualenvwrapper`. My python3 installation is at the bare bones now:

```
$ pip3 list
argparse (1.2.1)
pip (1.5.6)
setuptools (2.1)
stevedore (0.15)
virtualenv (1.11.6)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.5)
virtualenvwrapper (4.3.1)
```

As suggested by the tutorial, I added the following lines to my *.bashrc* file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```

which results in the following message when I open a new Terminal:

```
Last login: Wed Sep 10 22:33:17 on ttys006
-bash: _VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_API: unbound variable
-bash: VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT: unbound variable
-bash: VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT: unbound variable
-bash: _VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_API: unbound variable
-bash: _VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_API: unbound variable
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [-X filterpat] [-F function] [-C command] [name ...]
```

I don't understand what the problem is, but clearly the `source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh` line fails because then I can't even find the `mkvirtualenv` command:

```
$ mkvirtualenv test1 -p /usr/bin/python3.3
-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684231/python-setup-command-not-found) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855463/bash-mkvirtualenv-command-not-found), with similar problems, but none of them gave me a solution.

Comment: What else is in your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in my `.bashrc` file, the result of many years of work of adding different commands and functions from here and there.

Comment: Do you `set -u` in there?

Comment: I do `set -o notify`, `set -o noclobber`, `set -o ignoreeof`, `set -o nounset`.

Comment: Yeah, `set -o nounset` that's `set -u`. That's going to be the issue here. The preponderance of scripts out there aren't expecting to be run with that set as it makes many idiomatic actions fail. Disable that and see if it starts to work.

Comment: I now got `ERROR: virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh: Could not find virtualenvwrapper.sh`, and I guess it's because the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script is not on a default path?

Comment: Though it's recognizing the `mkvirtualenv` command now, but it doesn't seem to work: `$ mkvirtualenv test1 
-bash: : No such file or directory

[Process completed]`. After I see that message `[Process completed]` I can't do anything with the Terminal.

Comment: That message is your shell exiting (and your terminal telling you the session is dead), presumably because of something `mkvirtualenv` did (probably wrongly). The `PATH` idea looks like it might be right (if the file I'm looking at is the one you have). I don't know what might be going wrong with `mkvirtualenv` specifically though.

Comment: You don't have `errexit` on do you?

Comment: I haven't set anything related to `errexit` in my `.bashrc` file, just that when I open a new Terminal window I get the message `Last login: Wed Sep 10 23:25:04 on ttys000
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh: Could not find virtualenvwrapper.sh`.

Comment: Adjust your PATH so `which` can find that script and see if that fixes everything?

Comment: My PATH variable seems to have that directory already, 3 times... =/ and I'm not even adding that path in the `.bashrc` file. `$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/aaragon/Local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin`. So I can do `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` and it finds it.

Comment: Does it have it *before* you source `virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`?

Comment: It was after, so I fixed that and now the command is working. Yet, I don't think I can create the environment yet: `$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 pydev
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4'
New python executable in pydev/bin/python3
Also creating executable in pydev/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: That error shows up when I try to `workon` the environment: `$ workon pydev
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper`. Well, I haven't installed `virtualenvwrapper` with `python` but only in `python3`.

Comment: Does setting `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` fix that problem? I should point out that I am gathering all of this from looking at the scripts in question. I should also say that clearly something is wrong with either your setup or `virtualenv` itself if this much fiddling is required. It might make sense to find people who actually know/work with `virtualenv` to see what they make of all this.

Comment: After setting that environmental variable things get even worst because now when I type `workon pydev` I get again a `[Process completed]` message and the Terminal doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Like I said before `[Process completed]` means the shell that was being run in that window exited (in some way that didn't trigger the window to close, so perhaps an unclean exit). Also like I said, I think something is not quite right either with your system or with `virtualenv` itself but I'm not able to assess the `virtualenv` side of things and digging deeper into your system setup is an involved process. Sorry.

Comment: I was finally able to make it work. I took my `.bashrc` file and I cleaned, removed everything I didn't need. Now it works fine, but I still think the process of making `virtualenvwrapper` work is painful, as you have to add stuff to your profile file.

Comment: I will point out that there is a reason I asked what was in it at the start of all of this. =) I'm curious, if you are willing to share, what all you removed that might have been able to cause these myriad problems.

Comment: Well, I went to [this website](http://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/), and I took many things from there, which I mixed with my old `.bashrc`. I spent the entire morning doing that, in the end, I tried `virtualenvwrapper` and it was working already, but I really don't know what fixed it. I could send you both versions of the `.bashrc` file if you want.

Comment: Nothing in there looks overly harmful though the `cd` function and `which` alias could certainly cause some things problems.

Comment: I recall the `which` function being called within the `virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`. But I don't think this was the problem because I still have that alias, and it now works.

Answer (score 33):

I added the following in my .bashrc, referring [this](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#python-interpreter-virtualenv-and-path)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Now mkvirtualenv works-

```
pkoli@pkoli-SVE15136CNB:~/Desktop$ mkvirtualenv BUGS
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in BUGS/bin/python3
Also creating executable in BUGS/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

Comment: For my Kubuntu it was installed here: /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem and I fixed it with by following the tutorial:

http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/install-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-ubuntu/

#### Part 1: Install the required packages

`sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential`

`sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`

`sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

#### Part 2: Setup virtualenvwrapper in ~/.bashrc.

I used **vim** to edit ~/.bashrc.

**Firstly, install vim with the command:**

`sudo apt-get install vim`

**Secondly, edit ~/.bashrc**

`vi .bashrc`

`enter [Shift] + [g] //G (shift + g): to go the end of the file`

`enter [a] //Type a to edit the file`

Then insert three lines:

> `export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs`
>
> `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=[link-to-python-folder]`
>
> `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

where `[link-to-python-folder]` can be, for example:

- if you are using python 3,

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/user/bin/python3`

- if you are using python 2,

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/user/bin/python`

Next,
`enter [Esc] then :wq`

The **Esc** key means return the command line, **:wq** means save the changes and exit **vi**.

#### Part 3: Enable the virtual environment.

`source ~/.bashrc`

`mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME`

Now, you can try again with **mkvirtualenv**:

`mkvirtualenv your_project`

- To enable the 'your_project' virtual environment:

  `workon your_project`
- To exit it:

  `deactivate`

I noticed that when I installed separately virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper (with two times of 'sudo pip install'), I failed when run `source ~/.bashrc` because of a failure of the importing the module **virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader**, so although you really installed **virtualenv** and **virtualenvwrapper**, let try it one more time with `sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`.

Hope you find it useful!

Comment: Note that on step 2, I needed to add an extra line:
``export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3``

Answer (score 0):

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=~/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

If you have a clean installation of virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, then this should work in mac OS. It did for me.