# virtualenvwrapper not installing correctly?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to use a Python virtual environment for the first time while trying to learn Django. I am using the instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment). As I am using git bash on Windows, I am following the setup instructions for Windows.
I installed virtualenvwrapper using

`pip3 install virtualenvwrapper-win`

Now the command `mkvirtualenv` gets me `bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found`

I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855463/bash-mkvirtualenv-command-not-found) to no avail.

`pip3 list` shows that the package is, in fact, installed, but there is no virtualenvwrapper (or virtualenv) .sh files in the site-packages directory, and the only related file I can find is `virtualenvwrapper_win-1.2.5-py3.6.egg-info` in an AppData/Roaming directory.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried uninstalling `virtualenvwrapper-win`, just to see the list of files that would be removed. I saw that the `mkvirtualenv` was located in `C:\Python\Python37\Scripts`.

I noticed I was using the 64bit version of python (`C:\Python\Python37\`) alongside the 32bit one (`C:\Python\Python37-32\`), both folders being in the `PATH` of my system's properties. I removed the 32bit version's directories from the `PATH` and this seemed to work.

PS: I also noticed that running the commands from the `MINGW` terminal requires them to also have the .bat extension added:

[image]