# Getting "`mkvirtualenv: command not found`" after installing virtualenvwrapper on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, ubuntu-20.04

On Ubuntu *v20.04*, I have just installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` using `apt` with the commands:

```
sudo apt install virtualenv 
sudo apt install virtualenvwrapper
```

I did not get any errors or warnings.

When I try to run `mkvirtualenv`, which is claimed to be in `virtualenvwrapper`, I get:

```
mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855463/bash-mkvirtualenv-command-not-found) question presents an old solution (from 8 years ago) consisting of locating the file `virtualenvwrapper.sh` and adding it to the source.

However, this doesn't work anymore. When I type `source "/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"`, I get

```
bash: /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

When I use `locate` or `find` to search for this file throughout the computer, I get no results. When I type `which virtualenvwrapper` I get no result.

Trying to re-install the module again, I get:

```
sudo apt install virtualenvwrapper
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
virtualenvwrapper is already the newest version (4.8.4-4).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 18 not to upgrade.
```

What to do?

Comment: `dpkg-query -L` show that the package installs the file `/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.  Perhaps you should source that.

Comment: why do you install it with `atp` ? why not with `pip install virtualenv` ?

Comment: I can't install with `pip` because I'm using Anaconda. Thanks for giving my question a downvote, really appreciate it.

Comment: Please specify which version of which Linux distro the system in question is running.

Comment: Solved it with `dpkg-query -L`, then I found the file `virtualenvwrapper.sh` and could use `source` on that. I didn't know about this very specific command `dpkg-query -L`. Why weren't `find` or `locate` able to locate the file? Perhaps those commands are broken? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, sorry, I thought I had specified this.

Answer (score -1):

User [*phd* comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453125/getting-mkvirtualenv-command-not-found-after-installing-virtualenvwrapper-o/65454209#comment115721878_65454209) that `mkvirtualenv` is not an executable, it's a shell function provided by `virtualenvwrapper.sh`.  But if you don't know that to begin with, how would you find out?  Some tips:

1. Perhaps the executable name itself (*"`mkvirtualenv`"*) is incorrect.
   On my system, where neither package, *virtualenv* or
   *virtualenvwrapper*, is installed, if the user attempts to run any program name that's not installed but *could* be installed, the
   [*command-not-found* package](https://launchpad.net/command-not-found) will print an error message showing
   what package might need to be installed.

   It works even with *similar* sounding names -- so if we run a
   nonexistent command:

   ```
   bbash
   ```

   The output is:

   ```
   Command 'bbash' not found, did you mean:

     command 'bash' from deb bash (5.0-6ubuntu1.1)
     command 'rbash' from deb bash (5.0-6ubuntu1.1)

   Try: apt install <deb name>
   ```

   But if, on *Linux Mint 20*, I run the executable name given in the
   question:

   ```
   mkvirtualenv
   ```

   The output is:

   ```
   mkvirtualenv: command not found
   ```

   ...which implies such a command isn't even installable.
2. To find out the actual names and paths of programs installed with a
   given package that's already been installed on your system, use `dlocate -lsbin ...`, like so:

   ```
   dlocate -lsbin virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
   ```
3. To find the name of a not installed package containing a known file name, use `apt-file`:

   ```
   apt-file find virtualenv
   ```

   ...which finds the string *"virtualenv"* in the
   pathnames of all installable packages.

   To narrow the list to only file basenames that include the string *"virtualenv"*,
   do:

   ```
   f=virtualenv
   apt-file find $f | grep '[^/]*'"$f"'[^/]*$'
   ```

Comment: You don't need `dlocate`, you can simply run `dpkg -L` which is standard on every Debian-based system (or just inspect `/var/lib/dpkg/info/package.list` directly).

Comment: The `command-not-found` handler is specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: @tripleee, Not the same: `dpkg -L` lists *all* files in a package, but `dlocate -lsbin` lists only the executables.

Comment: True, but it doesn't do anything very fancy; basically, `grep 'bin/'`

Comment: `mkvirtualenv` is not an executable, it's a shell function provided by `virtualenvwrapper.sh`.